# Why firebase CLI push data to a random path on real-time database?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli

Why when I run this command on firebase CLI

```
firebase database:push /messages --data '{"users_test":"id","test","token"}'
```

I want the data to insert to `/data/messages/` in a real-time database

```
messages
   test: "token"
   users_test: "id"
```

But it always inserts to `/data/messages/`**-MbJqEUNN6EhisiyvbV8**

```
messages
 -MbJqEUNN6EhisiyvbV8
   test: "token"
   users_test: "id"
```

Why the random string is generated there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's literally what `database:push` does: it generates a unique ID under the location, and adds the data there.

If you want to write directly to the location, user `database:set`. That replaces any existing data at `messages` with the data you specify in the command.